# How to safely reboot an encrypted linux disk from command line?

Tags: boot, encryption

I've learned the hard way that

```
sudo reboot
```

at the wrong time is a great way to get a head slammed on your hard disk.

Is the only safe way to reboot Ubuntu running on encrypted LUKS to manually "killall" the processes you're aware of? Is there a ''' sudo safe-reboot''' command for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is `/sbin/shutdown`. Read `man shutdown`, and you can use it to reboot or halt. See `man shutdown`, which says, in part:

```
trusty (8) shutdown.8.gz
Provided by: upstart_1.12.1-0ubuntu4_i386 bug

NAME
       shutdown - bring the system down

SYNOPSIS
       shutdown [OPTION]...  TIME [MESSAGE]

DESCRIPTION
       shutdown arranges for the system to be brought down in a safe way.  All
       logged-in users are notified that the system is going down and,  within
       the last five minutes of TIME, new logins are prevented.
```